# Converting NSString to float produces inexact value

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, floating-point, nsstring, numbers

I have two text fields in my view. After prompting the user to enter a value, I convert them to `float`s to do my calculations.

I use the following code:

```
variable1 = [textField1.text floatValue];
variable2 = [textField2.text floatValue];`
```

When the user enters 22.8 in `textField1`, I get 22.80005 in `variable1`.

I do not get the exact value!

How do I get the exact decimal value? Any addition could affect the accuracy of the calculations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And another question hits SO about floating point accuracy!

You should use `NSDecimalNumber` instead:

```
NSDecimalNumber *variable1 = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[textField1 text]];
NSDecimalNumber *variable2 = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[textField2 text]];
```

There's some more info in the [Number and Value Programming Guide.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/DecimalNumbers.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can't: floating point numbers aren't exact values, only estimations, by definition. You are supposed to get such deviations.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on which calculations you are doing.

For currency use `NSDecimalNumber`.
For other calculations use `double` instead of a `float`. The precision problems arise when the number is converted from decadic to binary notation. `double` will give you better precision (not exact but more precise) and it should be enough for anything you want to do.

There are ways how to do exact calculations on computers but they are more complicated and always are much slower than `float` or `double`.

Comment: what about comparisons... i have an app in which i need to compare decimal values . The structure is such that the values are in string format and when i convert string to float, the precision is not exact eg converting -0.123456 from string to double returns -0.12345 but i need exact values..what should i do in this case

Comment: Usually you need exact values only in currency calculations. Exact numbers can be achieved with _fixed point arithmetics_ (basically you use an `long` or `long long` with fixed number of decimal places). Or you can use `NSDecimalNumber` which is designed for it.

Comment: actually the values are varying in digits after decimal, some have 6 , some have 9 some have 5 , like that

Comment: Use `NSDecimalNumber` or read something about implementing _fixed point arithmetics_.